# How are Cost centers related to Work orders?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I was assigned to do a report on all work orders related to a cost center. Can any sap guru explain how are cost center related to work orders with the related tables. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am afraid this is a consulting task. I assume you are a developer, responsible for a technical specification and writing the code. The person who wrote the funcional specification for this task must be able to show you which transactions, if not explicitly BAPIs you have to use in order to fulfill the requirements. This person also should be reponsible for preparing the test data for you. At least this is how it works in most of SAP projects.

Comment: @Jagger The guy is just asking for a start. You'd be wasting money if you paid a consultant to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I will teach you how to fish, but I will not feed you.

Basically a report like this will be simple in terms of ABAP skill, that is until your asked to do something more than just pick out work orders based on Cost Center.

Internal Orders or Work Orders are all Cost Center related. Each work order created has an assigned cost center and can be found in the following tables and structure.

COEP Controlling Object: Line Items by period.
This will have your Order number, item and also Cost Center.

COEJ Controlling Object: Line Items by year.
This will have the same by Year.

This is a start. You can also use t-code IW39 to pull up a Work Order. Then place the cursor on the field you have in question and hit F1, then in the dialog box choose the Technical Content Icon (Wrench/Hammer). That will bring you to the technical description of the field and will have table name etc...

Happy fishing, come back with more questions after you have had a chance to look at what I gave you. Also, give us some more info on your configuration.. Do you run PM?